# Combined code and nothing works. Head scratcher for sure

Tags: arduino-nano, datalogging, data

I have spent a little over 2 hours trying to debug this code. All I did was combine a section of code to write to the SD card. Both of the codes work fine on their own. I can't figure this one out. I am hoping fresh eyes can spot the error. I am using a Arduino Nano with a Robot-Deek data logger board. Pin 10 is used for the data logger. I was using a DTH11 but switched to a LM35, both codes worked with LM35.

```
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define sample 500 
#define current_ms millis()
RTC_DS1307 rtc;
File myFile;
int inPin = 0;   //analog in
float val;       //where to store info from inPin reading
int pinRed = A3;  //output of red led
float tempin = A5;  //input of temp sensor
float tempf;     // variable to hold temp in Fahrenheit
float vout;      // variable to hold voltage from sensor
int array1[sample];  //creates an array with number of elements equal to "sample"
unsigned long averaging;  //the program uses this variable to store the sum of each array it makes
int pinCS = 10;   // write to SD card
float last_dht11_reading_ms = 1;
DateTime now = rtc.now();
#define DHT11_SAMPLE_DELAY 500

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);//Delay to let system boot
  SD.begin();
  pinMode(pinCS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(tempin, INPUT);
  Serial.println("Volt and Temperature\n\n");
Serial.println("middle the setup loop");
 // SD Card Initialization
  if (SD.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("SD card is ready to use.");
    File myFile = SD.open("Datalog.csv",FILE_WRITE);
    if (myFile) {
      myFile.println("Time, Temp, Volt");
      myFile.close();
    }
  } else
  {
    Serial.println("SD card initialization failed");
    return;
  }
  rtc.begin();
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));    
}//end "setup()"

void loop() {

  for (int i = 0; i < sample; i++) {         //this code tells the program to fill each element in the array we made with
    array1[i] = analogRead(inPin);           //information from the antenna wire coming out of the Arduino
    averaging += array1[i];                  //more information about for loops http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/For
  }                                          //the averaging line is simply saying: add averaging to whatever is in array position i
                                             //averaging += array[i] is the same as averaging = averaging + array[i]

  val = averaging / sample;                  //here the program takes the sum of all numbers in array1, and divides by the number of elements "sample"
  val = constrain(val, 0, 100);              //this constrains the variable value to between two numbers 0 and 100
  val = map(val, 0, 100, 0, 255);           //for more information about constrain http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Constrain
  analogWrite(pinRed, val*20);                  //the map statement tells the program to map out 0-100 to 0-255
  averaging = 0;                                 //this line of code sets averaging back to zero so it can be used again
Serial.println("past the emf loop");

  if ( (current_ms - last_dht11_reading_ms) > DHT11_SAMPLE_DELAY ) {
    vout = analogRead(tempin);                //read LM35 output
    float mv = (vout/1024)*5000;              // conversion to mV
    float celc = mv/10;                       // convert to C
    float tempf = ((celc*9)/5 + 32)/10;       // convert to F
    myFile = SD.open("Datalog.csv", FILE_WRITE);      //open datalog file on SD card

  if (myFile) {                              //write to the SD card time, tempf and val
    myFile.print(now.hour());
    myFile.print(":");
    myFile.print(now.minute());
    myFile.print(":");
    myFile.print(now.second());
    myFile.print(",");     
    myFile.print(tempf);
    myFile.print(",");  
    myFile.println(val);
    myFile.close(); // close the file;    // close the file
    last_dht11_reading_ms = current_ms;
  }
Serial.println("past the logger loop");
  //delay(1000);//Wait 1 seconds before accessing sensor again.

}
}
// end loop()
```

Comment: What exactly is not working how? Please explain, what you expected and what behavior you actually see

Comment: I expect it to write to the SD card and write to the serial monitor. However it is not. I even put in some "markers" to print out to the serial monitor letting me know what part of the code fired off, but they don't print either. The LED does not work. It is like the code is not running.

Comment: remove the first SD.begin() and the pinMode for pinCS. add pinCS as parameter of the second SD.begin(). `if (SD.begin(pinCS))`

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes you suggested and still nothing. I run code A, no problem. I run code B, no problem. Run this code, a  combination of the two and I get nothing. No outputs.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime now = rtc.now();`
Does not belong above void setup()
4hours to troubleshoot this little mistake.